# Xcode debugger highlighting wrong line when I throw an exception

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to put a very simple unitTest-Like function together for teaching Swift, when we're not quite ready for the full XCTest framework.

I've put together this code:

```
enum TestFailure : Error {
    case testEqFailure(_ msg: String)
}

func testEq<E:Equatable>(_ actual: E, _ expected: E ) throws {
    if actual == expected { return }
    print("Test failed")
    print("Actual Result  : \(actual)")
    print("Expected Result: \(expected)")
    throw TestFailure.testEqFailure("Test Values were not equal")
}

try testEq(1,1)
try testEq(7,8)
```

It "works" just fine (as shown by the output):

```
Test failed
Actual Result  : 7
Expected Result: 8
Swift/ErrorType.swift:200: Fatal error: Error raised at top level: vPlay.TestFailure.testEqFailure("Test Values were not equal")
2021-11-01 10:36:52.050106-0400 vPlay[49261:2400984] Swift/ErrorType.swift:200: Fatal error: Error raised at top level: vPlay.TestFailure.testEqFailure("Test Values were not equal")
```

but when I run it, Xcode is highlighting the wrong source line:

[image: Xcode highlighting incorrect exception source line]

What am I missing?  (BTW, this is being used in the top level code of a command line program to keep things simple and focus on the actual coding)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the function with a do catch instead

```
try testEq(1,1)

do {
    try testEq(7,8)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

The error I get in playground is "An error was thrown and was not caught:" but not pointing to the first function call rather the second function call.

When you have a block of code that contains a method which can potentially throw an error you need to call the function with a do catch statement.
When the throwing method fails and raises the error the execution will go into the catch block and be handled according to what you dictate within the catch block.

The first function call is not failing because it doesn't throw an error  but if it is for whatever IDE your using then try a do catch on that call as well.

Comment: I understand how to use do/try/catch.  That’s a bit too much ceremony for this particular purpose.  I’m attempting to recreate the behavior of `assert()` except that I want the failure to dump the expected and actual values in a way that is easy for beginning programmers to set up.  Sort of a light-weight unit testing assertEquals.  I’m using XCode, so it’s not like I’m in left field with an IDE.  An assertion failure would stop on the source of the failure, and I’m looking to get the same behavior here.  What is not clear is why XCode highlights the prior call line.

Comment: When I used your exact code it also failed because of the second call being made for me though not the first like in yours. Why yours is pointing to the first idk but swift HAS to have a way to handle an error when you have a throwing function/method if a failure occurs. Try adding the do catch and see if the failure goes away, it should.

Comment: I realize i *could* add the exception handling.  I actually DO want it to fail.   Just trying to determine why, when it fails, it highlights the wrong line.  And yes, agree that a “proper” program has exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to teach a sudo assert test with a throwing function then you will have to teach error handling also or swift will fail when it has to handle the error being thrown.
You could eliminate the throwing and enum error if you want to simplify this for a beginner but still get the point across.

```
func testEq<E:Equatable>(_ actual: E, _ expected: E )  {
    if actual == expected { return }
    print("Test failed")
    print("Actual Result  : \(actual)")
    print("Expected Result: \(expected)")
    
}

testEq(1,1)
testEq(7,8)
```

This will print what you want to see, actual and expected with the print test failed along side it to simulate a failure.

Comment: Agreed, and it’s “not that bad”.  It’s just not as “in your face” as the IDE detecting the exception and highlighting the line that failed.  That is what happened with an `assert()`, but, when it fails, you don’t get to see the values easily.

Comment: Ya, I see what you're trying to do. It is def a tuff one to figure out how to work around without doing it the only way swift will truly allow. Maybe you could use the simple code from above to show them an easier way of how it works but also show them along side it an actual assert test and tell them here is what it will actually look like but under the hood this is the simple way to understand it with this function.